# Fix function in R for Ubuntu not working properly

Tags: r, function

I have been using R in the terminal window for Ubuntu. Recently I discovered the `fix` function in R, which I could use to edit my function. However, whenever I use the fix function, it opens up an editor (VIM) and I can use that to write my function. Then I type "wq" to save the work, however when I type the name of the function, it shows that there weren't any edits which were made to the function. Why does this happen?

Comment: Do you type "[ESC]" ":wq"? (works like expected on Debian)

Comment: I did, it worked before, but for some reason,  its not working now.

Comment: works for me (Ubuntu 10.04, vim 7.2, R 2.15.1 and development versions) ... maybe try setting `option(editor="somethingelse")` and seeing if the problem is vim-specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the editing functionality, make sure you have either

- the default editor installed (do eg `grep EDITOR /etc/R/Renviron`)
- or set the `EDITOR` environment variable to a different editor you prefer,
- or at runtime set `options("editor"=....)` to what you need.

Now, for the **`fix()`** function in particular, note this hint in its manual page:

> ```
>  ‘fix’ invokes ‘edit’ on ‘x’ and then assigns the new (edited)
>  version of ‘x’ in the user's workspace.
> ```

So if the change "vanishes", maybe you were editing an object which is not yours.  Start with something simple, edit it and see if that persists. Along the lines of

```
R> hw <- function() cat("Hello, world\n")
R> fix(hw)                 ## editing, adding 'new'
R> hw()
Hello, new world
R>
```